# AutoHotkey make remove less than typed

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use Autohotkey as auto correct function such as MS Word by doing like `::tihs::this` not only in English but Korean.

As I've tested as like `::이거::이것`, Korean is not recognized even the .ahk file saved with UTF-8 format. for instead, As 이거 and 이것 are same strokes with `dlrj` and `dlrjt` in English so I wrote; `::dlrj::dlrjt`

The code replace the letter in Korean fine as the Autohotkey do not care about the the input setting is in English or not, but problem with the code is, it remove four characters for first and then rewrite the correction so the result example like this; `123456이거 → 1234이것`

Can I force the code to remove only two letters in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this code from [autohotkey forum](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=54502&p=235134#p235134)

```
:B0:dlrj::{Bs 3}dlrjt
```